# How to find inverse of a composite function?

Tags: functions

I am stuck with this question,

> Let $A=B=C=\mathbb{R}$ and consider the functions $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon B\to C$ defined by $f(a)=2a+1$, $g(b)=b/3$. Verify Theorem 3(b): $(g\circ f)^{-1}=f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}.$

I have calculated $f^{-1}$, $g^{-1}$,  and their composition, but how do I find the inverse of $(g\circ f)$?

Here is how I have done so far,

> $$\begin{align*}
> \text{Let}\qquad\qquad b &= f(a)\\
> a&= f^{-1}(b)\\
> &{ }\\
> b&=f(a)\\
> b&=2a+1\\
> \frac{b-1}{2} &= a\\
> a &= \frac{b-1}{2}
> \end{align*}$$
>   But $a=f^{-1}(b)$,
>   $$f^{-1}(b) = \frac{b-1}{2}.$$

${}$

> $$\begin{align*}
> \text{Let}\qquad\qquad a&=g(b)\\
> b&= g^{-1}(a)\\
> a&= g(b)\\
> a &= b/3\\
> b &= 3a\\
> g^{-1}(a) &= 3a\qquad(\text{because }b=g^{-1}(a)
> \end{align*}$$

${}$

> $$\begin{align*}
> f^{-1}\circ g^{-1} &= ?\\
> &= f^{-1}\Bigl( g^{-1}(a)\Bigr)\\
> &= f^{-1}(3a)\\
> f^{-1}\circ g^{-1} &= \frac{3a-1}{2}
> \end{align*}$$
>
> $$\begin{align*}
> g\circ f&= g\bigl(f(a)\bigr)\\
> &= g(2a+1)\\
> g\circ f &= \frac{2a+1}{3}\\
> (g\circ f)^{-1} &= ?\\
> \text{Let}\qquad\qquad &b=g\circ f
> \end{align*}$$

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the answers, I followed the suggestions and came up with the answer,
[image]
[image]
Now I have two questions,

1. The answers do match but the arguments are different. Is that ok?
2. Is $(g\circ f)$ same as $(g\circ f(a))$?

Comment: $(g\circ f)$ is a function. $(g\circ f(a))$ is the value of the function $g\circ f$ at $a$. They are not the same thing (one is a function, the other is an number that you've written in parentheses). The name of the variable doesn't matter. The function $g(x)=x^2$ is the same as the function $g(z)=z^2$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$f,g$ are the functions defined in the question.

[image]

We have

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
b &=&f(a)=2a+1, 
\end{eqnarray*}$$

or equivalently, by definition of the inverse function $f^{-1}$

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
&a=\frac{b-1}{2}=f^{-1}(b).\tag{A}
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Since

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
c &=&g(b)=\frac{b}{3}, 
\end{eqnarray*}$$

or equivalently, by definition of the inverse function $g^{-1}$

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
b=3c=g^{-1}(c),\tag{B}
\end{eqnarray*}$$

after combining $(A)$ and $(B)$, we get

$$a=\frac{3c-1}{2}=(f^{-1}\circ g^{-1})(c).\tag{1}$$

On the other hand

$$c=(g\circ f)(a)=g(f(a))=g(2a+1)=\frac{2a+1}{3}.\tag{2}$$

Hence, by definition, the value at $c$ of the inverse function $(g\circ f)^{-1}$, is

$$a=\frac{3c-1}{2}=(g\circ f)^{-1}(c).\tag{3}$$

From $(1)$ and $(3)$ we conclude that for these functions $f,g$ and their inverses $f^{-1},g^{-1}$ the following identity holds:

$$(f^{-1}\circ g^{-1})(c)=(g\circ f)^{-1}(c).\tag{4}$$

*Notation's note*: $(f^{-1}\circ g^{-1})(c)=f^{-1}(g^{-1}(c))$.

Comment: @fahad: You are welcome.

Comment: @AméricoTavares I usually draw the function in this way eevry time it helps me with composition of functions and when I "play" with algebraic structures but I was always scared to use them in order to explain my concepts in my questions to other people because I believed I was taking too much freedom with a notation that I only saw in cathegory theory, where your sets A,B and C are usually set with sturctures. So is correct to use these "diagrams" even outside the cathegory theory context?

Comment: @MphLee I am not a mathematician and know nothing about cathegory theory, but these diagrams appeared in some books of Calculus/Real Analysis for Engineers back in 1060-1970's.

Comment: @AméricoTavares and I'm even less a mathematican I'll try to search more about this and I'll continue use these diagrams in my amatorial practice, thanks anyways

Comment: There are diagrams similar to this for showing all sorts of maps between sets in my textbook on Smooth Manifolds by John Lee. At the end of the day,  what matters for notation is that it accurately represents the mathematics in a way that helps you better understand it and that it will be correctly interpreted by anybody else who needs to read it. Your diagram is clear and intuitive and it is reasonably consistent with conventions, so in my opinion it is good notation.

Answer (score 4):

What you've done so far is to compute $f^{-1}$ and $g^{-1}$, and $f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$. Now you want to try to find $(g\circ f)^{-1}$ directly, and compare that to what you've computed (in order to verify the formula).

So, you've figured out that $(g\circ f)(a) = \frac{2a+1}{3}$. How do we figure out $(g\circ f)^{-1}$?

Exactly the same way we figure out the inverse of any function. If someone stopped you on the street, pointed a gun at you and said

> "Here, I have this function:
>   $$h(a) = \frac{2a+1}{3},$$
>   I need the formula for $h^{-1}$. Give it to me or I'll shoot you!"

then you don't need to know *where* that function came from, all you need to do is figure out the inverse:
$$\begin{align*}
b &= \frac{2a+1}{3}\\
3b &= 2a+1\\
3b-1 &= 2a\\
&\vdots
\end{align*}$$
etc. When you are done and have a formula for $h^{-1}(a) = (g\circ f)^{-1}(a)$, you can compare it to the formula you found for $f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$ and verify that you got the same function.

Comment: Thanks alot. I did it as you suggested. A small problem that I am having is that is in terms of b instead of a. Checkout the edit.

Comment: @fahad: Don't get hung up on the letters. The name of the variable is immaterial. The function $h(x) = x^2$ is exactly the same as the function $h(y)=y^2$, which is exactly the same as the function $h(z)=z^2$, which is exactly the same as the function $h(a)=a^2$. Just switch all the $b$s into $a$s and be done.

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer :)

Comment: I can't resist adding that the Russian mathematical physicist Igor Tamm was once [told to do a mathematics calculation or be shot](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28885/anecdotes-about-famous-mathematicians-or-physicists/28899#28899). :)

Answer (score 3):

You find the inverse of $g\circ f$ by using the fact that $(g\circ f)^{-1} = f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}$.

In other words, what gets done last gets undone first.

$f$ multiplies by 2 and then adds 1.

$g$ divides by 3.

Dividing by 3 is done last, so it's undone first.

The inverse first multiplies by 3, then undoes $f$.

**Later note:** Per the comment, to *verify* that $(g\circ f)^{-1} = f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}$:

Instead of confusingly writing $a = g(b)$, write $c=g(b)$.  Then $c=b/3$, so $b=3c$, so
$$g^{-1}(c) = 3c.$$  And $$f^{-1}(b) = \frac{b-1}{2}.$$

So
$$
b = 3c\qquad\text{and}\qquad a = \frac{b-1}{2}.
$$
Put $3c$ where $b$ is and get
$$
a=\frac{3c-1}{2}.
$$
You want to show that that's the *same* as what you'd get by finding $g(f(a))$ directly and *then* inverting.

So $c = g(f(a)) = \dfrac{f(a)}{3} = \dfrac{2a+1}{3}$.

So take $c = \dfrac{2a+1}{3}$ and solve it for $a$:

$$
\begin{align}
3c & = 2a+1 \\
3c - 1 & = 2a \\  \\
\frac{3c-1}{2} & = a.
\end{align}
$$

**FINALLY,** observe that you got the same thing both ways.

Comment: But the problem asks the student to *verify* the formula; that is, find the inverse of $g\circ f$ "directly", and then compare it to the function you get by computing $f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$. Surely using the formula to verify that the formula works is a tad... unsatisfying.

Comment: I am stuck with how do I find (gof)^-1

Comment: OK, I've added a later note.

Comment: @MichaelHardy thank you for this answer, it came in handy for a question I recently asked