# Why is this the closed-form solution for this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

I know this is simple, but I don't know very much at all about series, and I'm wondering how it's shown that:

$$ 1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + (n - 1) = \frac{n(n - 1)}{2} $$

Comment: This question is [basically the same as this previously asked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-ldotsn). It's just that you stop at $n-1$ and this question stops at $n$.

Comment: For inspiration on this sum, look up the famous anecdote about Gauss as a young boy doing such a sum, alluded to in [this Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28885/anecdotes-about-famous-mathematicians-or-physicists).  Once you see the trick, you will find it easier to remember than the formula itself.

Comment: A neat proof of this formula can be obtained by induction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The average of $1$ and $n-1$ is $\dfrac n 2$.

The average of $2$ and $n-2$ is $\dfrac n 2$.

The average of $3$ and $n-3$ is $\dfrac n 2$.

The average of $4$ and $n-4$ is $\dfrac n 2$.

and so on $\ldots$

So the average of all of them is $\dfrac n 2$:
$$
\frac{1+2+3+\cdots+(n-1)}{n-1} = \frac n 2.
$$

Comment: I like this one, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The simple way to understand it is to sum the following sums:
$$S=1+2+...+(n-2)+(n-1)$$
$$S=(n-1)+(n-2)+\cdots+2+1$$
These sums are the same, just flipped.

The result is:
$$2S=(1+n-1)+(2+n-2)+(n-1+1)=n+n+\cdots+n$$
The number of terms $n$ in the $2S$ is $(n-1)$, so $2S=n(n-1)$, and hence:
$$S=1+2+\cdots+(n-1)=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$