# Looking for details on historical math anecdote

Tags: soft-question, math-history

My memory is very sketchy here so bear with me. A fairly prominent 19th or 20th century mathematician was captured by a military force, probably invaders. He claimed that he was just a civilian, a mathematician, and in order to prove that he was a non combatant he had to talk about, what was at the time, cutting edge mathematics. Anybody know who this was and can link me to more details?

Comment: This seems more appropriate for [hsm.se] than [math.se].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an apocryphal story about the Russian mathematical physicist and Nobel Laureate Igor Tamm. In the story, he was said to stopped by highwaymen and was released upon answering a quiz question about Maclaurin Series.

The story is recounted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28885/anecdotes-about-famous-mathematicians-or-physicists), though the quoted source is down. At [this](http://www.3quarksdaily.com/3quarksdaily/2008/06/taylor-series-.html) site we see the same story, but this time he is suspected of being a communist agitator

His Wikipedia page can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igor_Tamm)

Answer (score 1):

This story is told in the Encyclopedia Britannica about Sophus Lie, who invented, or studied, Lie groups.

Comment: Not the story I was looking for but still applicable and interesting.